# Excelの特定のバージョンへアップデートするには

Tags: excel

MSI版のExcelを使用しているのですが、動作検証のため、特定のバージョンへアップデートを行いたいです。
C2R版にはバージョンの指定方法があるのですが、MSI版は調べてもありませんでした。
MSI版で特定のバージョンにするためには、更新プログラムを一個ずつインストールしていくしか方法がないのでしょうか。
また、office2016の共通のバージョンはMSO.dllで保持しているとの記事があり、MSO.dllが指定したいバージョンの更新プログラムをインストールしてもバージョンは変わりませんでした。

Comment: 単純に現在のものをアンインストールして、希望のパッケージ形態・版数のものをインストールすれば良いのでは？ そうではなくて共存・併用させる場合は、可不可を含めてこちらの記事が参考になりそうです。[異なるバージョンの Office を同じ PC にインストールして使う](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/6ebb44ce-18a3-43f9-a187-b78c513788bf) どういう形に持っていきたいのかの詳細を追記した方が良いでしょう。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。言葉足らずで申し訳ございません。Officeは同じものをインストールしているので、パッケージのバージョン等は一致しております。しかし、16.0.XXXXのマイナーバージョン部分も同じにしたく質問した次第です。

Comment: そうするとこちらの記事が参考になるかもしれません。[以前のバージョンのファイルに戻すOffice](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/topic/2bd5c457-a917-d57e-35a1-f709e3dda841)

Comment: @kunif 日本語表示だと機械翻訳で分かりづらいですが、以下の記載があります。"This article doesn’t apply to MSI versions of Office."

Comment: そうすると既読だと思われますがこの辺の記事でしょうか。[Windows インストーラー (MSI) を使用しているバージョンの Office の最新の更新プログラム](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/officeupdates/office-updates-msi), [Windows インストーラー (MSI) を使用しているバージョンの Office の最新のセキュリティ以外の更新プログラム](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/officeupdates/office-msi-non-security-updates), [Office の更新プログラムをインストールする](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/2ab296f3-7f03-43a2-8e50-46de917611c5) またはこんなサービスで情報が得られるかも。[Microsoft 365 開発者プログラムへようこそ](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/developer-program/microsoft-365-developer-program)

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。返信が遅れ申し訳ございません。リンクを一通り確認いたしました。[以前のバージョンのファイルに戻すOffice](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/topic/%E4%BB%A5%E5%89%8D%E3%81%AE%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%81%AE%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AB%E6%88%BB%E3%81%99office-2bd5c457-a917-d57e-35a1-f709e3dda841)ではMSI版には対応していないようでしたので、特定バージョンに上げることができませんでした。更新プログラムのリンクについてですが、該当バージョンの更新プログラムを適用してもバージョンが上がりませんでした。おそらく、Microsoftが公開しているのは更新プログラム単体だけのため、今までに適用されている更新プログラムが適用されていないからだと思われます。もう一度調べてみてバージョンを上げる方法を探してみます。回答ありがとうございました。